# Put C++ class in C-struct for for use in C++ function (C/C++ mixed code)

Tags: c++, c, class, struct, static

**NOTE**: This is not about C/C++ linkage or the extern keyword. Please read carefully before associating my question with seemingly similar questions, thank you!

I think this is a somewhat unusual problem as I didn't find anything on this while browsing the web.

I'm programming an embedded system. The main module is written in C while a submodule is written in C++. To illustrate this:

```
    submodule.hpp
   /            \
  /              \
main.c        submodule.cpp
```

Now I want to hold on to the data that is used by the C++-submodule and contain it in a static variable in my main script so I can call submodule functions from main and provide context data with every call. But that data must also contain a class as it is used by the submodule functions, but of course C doesn't know how to deal with classes. So I have to covertly put a class into my C-struct without main.c-script noticing (giving me an error). How could I achieve this?

I figured something like this could work:

```
struct data_for_cpp_submodule {
   int a;
   int b;
   void *class;
}
```

And then casting the void pointer "class" back to the appropriate class so I can work with it in the C++ script. Could this work or am I going about it completely the wrong way?

Comment: I'd consider doing it the reverse way. Use a C-struct and implement a class which can handle it. The other way around seems somewhere between impossible und unwise.

Comment: Carrying a pointer to a C++ class around is fine.   Dereferencing that pointer in C code will give undefined behaviour (except in specific cases, such as the class being POD).   Casting in the  C++ code will work, as long as you cast to a valid type (e.g. if the object is of type `A`, casting the pointer to an `A*`).    If you pass a `struct data_for_cpp_submodule` from C to C++ code, the definition of that type would need to be valid in both C and C++ - which means several things, such as the pointer cannot be named `class` (since `class` is a keyword in C++).

Comment: You can do it this way, but do think about ownership. If the C code owns the object you'll need 1 function each initialization and deinitialization (basically the functionality of using `new`/`delete` for the C++ object). If the object is owned by the C++ side, any unique id suitable for identifying the object would be sufficient. You could e.g. create objects in a vector and provide the index to your C code; providing a void pointer should be fine as long as you can guarantee that the C code doesn't try to access the object after you delete it on the C++ side.

Comment: *I figured something like this could work:*  That works only because that C++ "class" is really nothing more than a C `struct`.  The **only** type of class that can be included in a C `struct` is one that is nothing more than a C `struct`.  Anything else simply can't be done because C has no syntax to handle actual C++ `class` constructs.  So the only thing that shoehorning a C `struct` into a C++ class will get you is someone in the future putting actual C++-specific code into that C-struct-masquerading-as-a-C++-class and breaking things. Hopefully spectacularly so it's fixed immediately...

Comment: One problem: you can't name that pointer `class`. `class` is a reserved word in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Please, note that OP emphasized:

> The main module is written in C while a submodule is written in C++.

IMHO, it's completely fine to add a C binding for the C++ `submodule`, so that it can be used in C code.

The example of OP (enhanced a bit to make it an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)):

**C++ code for `submodule`**:

header `submodule.hpp`:

```cpp
#ifndef SUB_MODULE_HPP
#define SUB_MODULE_HPP

class Test {

  private:
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    
  public:
    Test() = default; // default constructor
    Test(int a, int b): a(a), b(b) { } // value constructor
    Test(Test&) = delete; // say: copy constructor disabled
    Test& operator=(Test&) = delete; // say: copy assignment disabled
    
  public:
    int exec() const;
};

#endif // SUB_MODULE_HPP
```

source `submodule.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "submodule.hpp"

int Test::exec() const { return a + b + 42; }
```

**C Binding for `submodule`:**

header: `submodule.h`

```cpp
#ifndef SUB_MODULE_H
#define SUB_MODULE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

struct TestC_;
typedef struct TestC_ TestC; // opaque structure

extern TestC* testNew();

extern TestC* testNewValues(int a, int b);

extern void testDelete(TestC *pTest);

extern int testExec(TestC *pTest);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // SUB_MODULE_H
```

source `submoduleC.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "submodule.h"
#include "submodule.hpp"

TestC* testNew() { return (TestC*)new Test(); }

TestC* testNewValues(int a, int b) { return (TestC*)new Test(a, b); }

void testDelete(TestC *pTest) { delete (Test*)pTest; }

int testExec(TestC *pTest) { return ((Test*)pTest)->exec(); }
```

Last but not least: **A sample C program using `submodule`:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include "submodule.h"

int main(void)
{
  TestC *pTest = testNew();
  printf("pTest->exec(): %d\n", testExec(pTest));
  testDelete(pTest);
  
  pTest = testNewValues(123, -123);
  printf("pTest->exec(): %d\n", testExec(pTest));
  testDelete(pTest);
}
```

How it has to be compiled and linked with `g++`/`gcc`:

```
$ ## compile C++ code
$ g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -c submodule.cpp submoduleC.cpp
$ ## compile C code
$ gcc -std=c11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -lstdc++ main.c submodule.o submoduleC.o
$ ## test
$ ./a.out
```

Output:

```
testExec(pTest): 42
testExec(pTest): 42
```

[**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac5658d0829279ac)

The most notable part might be the `opaque structure`:

```c
struct TestC_;
typedef struct TestC_ TestC; // opaque structure
```

(This is what I learnt from other C bindings before I started to write my own.)

It might be surprising that the `opaque structure` is actually an incomplete structure but that's intentional.

The opaque structure is intended to be used as pointer only in C. It's not intended to allow dereferencing of any contents (and, for an incomplete structure, this is merely denied by the compiler). It's only purpose is to "tunnel" a pointer to a C++ `Test` instance through the C code.

In the C binding of `Test` (`submoduleC.cpp`), `TestC*` is simply converted to `Test*` (and vice versa) where necessary.

**Hint:**

I had to link `-lstdc++` (the standard C++ library). Otherwise, I got complaints about undefined references for the operators `new` and `delete`:

```
submoduleC.o: In function `testNew':
submoduleC.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
submoduleC.o: In function `testNewValues':
submoduleC.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
submoduleC.o: In function `testDelete':
submoduleC.cpp:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

**Other thoughts (but probably not that relevant)**:

I remember a prominent framework which

- is written in C
- and provides a C++ API (aka. C++ binding).

I'm talking about [GTK+](https://www.gtk.org/) and [gtkmm](https://www.gtkmm.org/en/) (its C++ binding).
Thereby, it should be mentioned that GTK+ is actually an OOP library – providing object-oriented classes implemented in C. (I'm uncertain whether this fact makes things easier or harder concerning the C++ binding.)

Both are Open Source projects. Hence, everybody can have a look at it how did they do. I once had a look and was impressed…

This aside, I always would recommend the opposite: writing a library in C++ and adding a C binding as this appears much easier to me.

We always did this in Windows for multiple reasons:

1. to achieve that DLLs compiled with different versions of Visual Studio can be linked together. (Until soon, this was nearly impossible with C++ but now, I believe, I read about an ABI introduced by Microsoft which may it make possible.)
2. to provide a base for bindings in other languages like e.g. C#.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of how to put an actual C++ class into a C `struct`.  Of course that question can't be answered because it can't be done...